# unsupported format character error in youtube-dl

Tags: syntax-error, youtube-dl, ubuntu-20.04

i've been trying to download a youtube playlist using youtube-dl, but i had a problem in the output template, i used the following command to get the playlist downloaded in an organised way :

```
youtube-dl -f mp4 -o "Desktop/mainFolder/courses/%(playlist_title)s-%(playlist_uploader)/%(title)s.%(ext)s" --embed-thumbnail --add-metadata --mark-watched https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzH6n4zXuckpfMu_4Ff8E7Z1behQks5ba
```

but i kept getting the following error :

```
ERROR: Error in output template: unsupported format character '/' (0x2f) at index 66 (encoding: 'UTF-8')
```

it states that i used an unsupported character which is '/', weirdly enough i used almost the same output template format in a previous download which is :

```
youtube-dl -f mp4 -o "Desktop/mainFolder/courses/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s" --add-metadata https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4C9296DF81B9EF13
```

and it worked just fine.
what did i did differently here so that the first command didn't work but the last one did ??

Answer (score 7):

If you see this error it probably means one of the format expressions doesn't end with an `s`.

In this case, it looks like you're missing one after `(playlist_uploader)`.

```
youtube-dl -f mp4 -o "Desktop/mainFolder/courses/%(playlist_title)s-%(playlist_uploader)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s" --embed-thumbnail --add-metadata --mark-watched https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzH6n4zXuckpfMu_4Ff8E7Z1behQks5ba
```

Comment: Banged my head on this one all night until I found this. Thank you so much!